# MySQL Select values indirectly by diverse 'column-name'

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL use column names from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281520/mysql-use-column-names-from-another-table)

I have two tables:

- TABLE_1 with some words extracted from any text; and
- TABLE_2 with the Words (in columns) frequency in the related text

[image]

I´d like to produce a TABLE_3 with the Author_Id and words (in rows) present in the text:

[Table 3 http://www.infociencias.net/images/tab3.jpg](http://www.infociencias.net/images/tab3.jpg)

How to do this in MySQL?

Comment: Sigh.  _What have you tried?_

Comment: can you post what you want as the result?

Comment: SELECT B.Author_Id, A.Column_Name 

FROM Table_1 A, Table_2 B, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C

WHERE table_name = 'Table_2' AND Column_Name = A.Column_Name

Comment: I´d like to have the TABLE_3 as the result:
[link to view TABLE_3](http://www.infociencias.net/images/tab3.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This is an `UNPIVOT` that you are attempting to do but MySQL does not have an `UNPIVOT` function so you will need to replicate it using a `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT c.author_id, words, value
FROM Table1 A
INNER JOIN
(
  select author_id, alfa value, 'alfa' col
  from table2
  union all
  select author_id, car value, 'car' col
  from table2
  union all
  select author_id, zoom value, 'zoom' col
  from table2
) C 
  ON A.words = C.col
order by c.author_id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ffc0/9)

result:

```
| AUTHOR_ID | WORDS | VALUE |
-----------------------------
|       123 |  alfa |     3 |
|       123 |  zoom |     0 |
|       123 |   car |     0 |
|       157 |  alfa |     0 |
|       157 |  zoom |     2 |
|       157 |   car |     0 |
|       332 |  alfa |     1 |
|       332 |  zoom |     0 |
|       332 |   car |     3 |
|       519 |   car |     0 |
|       519 |  alfa |     0 |
|       519 |  zoom |     0 |
|       588 |   car |     1 |
|       588 |  alfa |     5 |
|       588 |  zoom |     0 |
|       777 |   car |     0 |
|       777 |  alfa |     0 |
|       777 |  zoom |     1 |
|       804 |   car |     7 |
|       804 |  alfa |     0 |
|       804 |  zoom |     5 |
```

Comment: Hi, bluefeet! It would be ok if I could know the words previously, but I can´t. Each different text has different words. So, the words alfa, car, zoom are occasional in the table, unfortunately. I really need a dinamic solution.

Comment: @RomualdoAlves you will have to look at creating a procedure to generate this sql dynamically and then executing it.